# Looking for a generic name substitute in Elvish, Draconic, Celestial, or Sylvan

Tags: dnd-5e, languages

I have a Far Traveler Sorcerer High Elf character who has lost most of his early memories so he does not remember his name. I am looking for a generic word or name substitute to make him more playable in one of the languages he is fluent in: Elvish, Draconic, Celestial, or Sylvan. Some suggestions for a translation would be "the sorcerer" or "wanderer" or "traveler" or even "name".

Comment: Rather than asking for a "generic word or name substitute", which is sort of an idea-generation question with no way to choose a single "best" answer, it might be better to ask whether there are official dictionaries or lexicons for any of those languages in D&D. (Then, if such resources do exist, you could browse them and settle on an appropriate name substitute yourself.) Alternately, you could ask whether there are official translations of a list of set terms into those languages. ...Also, are you open to material from previous editions as well?

Comment: Yes, I think my DM would be okay with that. So yes, I'd be open to previous edition material.

Answer (score 6):

*Races of the Dragon* for D&D 3.5e had a guide to Draconic in the back on page 147.

> | Common | Draconic |
> | --- | --- |
> | adventurer | toovir |
> | elf | vaecaesin |
> | friend | thurirl |
> | male | sthyr |
> | secret | irthos |
> | sorcerer | vorastrix |
> | wizard | levethix |

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Are there any of those for the other languages I mentioned?

Comment: @NeonKraken I don’t think so; I usually use Tolkien’s Quenya or Sindarin for elf characters, personally.

Comment: A DMsGuild link, in case you want to include it (or if OP wants to get the book): https://www.dmsguild.com/product/28750/Races-of-the-Dragon-35